# manipulate text using shell script?

Tags: shell, awk

How can i manipulate the text file using shell script?

input

```
chr2:98602862-98725768
chr11:3100287-3228869
chr10:3588083-3693494
chr2:44976980-45108665
```

expected output

```
2 98602862 98725768
11 3100287 3228869
10 3588083 3693494
2 44976980 45108665
```

Comment: what is the logic here? try to describe it in a way that makes sense and also provide your attempts, since this seems quite basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` you can write

```
$ sed 's/chr//; s/[:-]/ /g' file
2 98602862 98725768
11 3100287 3228869
10 3588083 3693494
2 44976980 45108665
```

---

Or maybe you could use `awk`

```
awk -F "chr|[-:]" '{print $2,$3, $4}' file
2 98602862 98725768
11 3100287 3228869
10 3588083 3693494
2 44976980 45108665
```

**What it does**

- `-F "chr|[-:]"` sets the field separators to `chr` or `:` or `-`. Now you could print the different fields or columns.
- You can also use another field separator as `-F [^0-9]+` which will makes anything other than digits as separators.

Comment: Alternatively using awk, the field separator could be `[^0-9]+` (i.e. one or more non-digits).

Comment: @TomFenech Good point.Added to a answer. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about a leading blank char:

```
$ tr -s -c '[0-9\n]' ' ' < file
 2 98602862 98725768
 11 3100287 3228869
 10 3588083 3693494
 2 44976980 45108665
```